# Python/Pandas: Delete duplicates if three conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, duplicates

I would like to delete duplicates from a data frame but I am stuck as I want three conditions to be met at the same time. How can this be achieved using Pandas?

Please find my code so far bellow:

```
import pandas as pd

list_name = ['Joe', 'Sarina', 'Paul', 'Ana', 'Joe', 'Sarina']
list_surname = ['Day', 'Summers', 'Smith', 'Baker', 'Day', 'Brown']
list_letter = ['a','b','c','d','a','b']

df_profiles = pd.DataFrame({'Name': list_name, 'Surname': list_surname, 'Letter':list_letter})

# Checking for duplicates using isin() and duplicated()
# Sorting them by index order
name = df_profiles['Name']
surname = df_profiles['Surname']
letter = df_profiles['Letter']

# If ALL these three are true delete duplicate
df_profiles[name.isin(name[name.duplicated()])].sort_values('Name').sort_index()
df_profiles[surname.isin(surname[surname.duplicated()])].sort_values('Surname').sort_index()
df_profiles[letter.isin(letter[letter.duplicated()])].sort_values('Letter').sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

We have `all`

```
df=df_profiles[~df_profiles.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, keep=False).all(1)]

df
Out[84]: 
     Name  Surname Letter
1  Sarina  Summers      b
2    Paul    Smith      c
3     Ana    Baker      d
5  Sarina    Brown      b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the conditions with `&` and get the negation of that with `~`:

```
df_profiles = df_profiles[~(name.isin(name[name.duplicated()]) &  
                            surname.isin(surname[surname.duplicated()]) &  
                            letter.isin(letter[letter.duplicated()]) 
                           )]
```

Result:

```
     Name  Surname Letter
1  Sarina  Summers      b
2    Paul    Smith      c
3     Ana    Baker      d
5  Sarina    Brown      b
```